# Sorting custom object List in kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, arraylist

```
interface Feed

class Memo : Feed {
    var memoId: String? = null
    var updateTime: String? = null
//    other fileds
}

class Activity : Feed {
    var activityId: String? = null
    var updateTime: String? = null
//    other fileds
}
```

As above code, I have Created one interface and extend it in the other two classes.

```
   var mainFeedList: ArrayList<Feed> = ArrayList()
   var memoList: ArrayList<Memo> = ArrayList()
   var ActivityList: ArrayList<Activity> = ArrayList()

    fun arrangeFeedDataOrder() {
   
        mainFeedList.addAll(memoList)
        mainFeedList.addAll(ActivityList)

        mainFeedList.sortedBy {
            when (it) {
                is Activity -> {
                    it.updateTime
                }
                is Memo -> {
                    it.updateTime
                }
                else -> {
                    null
                }
            }
        }
//        Not work above code for sorting
    }
```

I have the main list which contains memos and activity data. I want to sort this list with **updateTime** filed. I used **sortedBy** function but it does not work in my case. Anyone has an idea how to sort the list?

Comment: Why doesn't `sortedBy` work for you? You're not actually assigning the result to anything in your code, it's not an in-place sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `sortBy` (sorts the list in place) instead of `sortedBy` (returns a sorted copy, which you're basically discarding)

Also, why not put `updateTime` in the interface if it's something common to all `Feed`s? That way you don't need to do any type checking - you have a list of `Feed`s, they have an `updateTime`, so you can just sort by `it.updateTime` on all of them:

```
interface Feed {
    var updateTime: String?
}

class Memo : Feed {
    var memoId: String? = null
    override var updateTime: String? = null
}

class Activity : Feed {
    var activityId: String? = null
    override var updateTime: String? = null
}

...

mainFeedList.sortBy { it.updateTime } // or sortBy(Feed::updateTime)
```

or if you have a superclass for those classes, you could just define the property in there with the default `null` value (can't do that in an interface, which is why you need to `override` and provide a value in each class that implements it)

Comment: You can't sort by a nullable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You can? Nulls end up first in the list - https://pl.kotl.in/SKDs9HlkB

Comment: Wow, I never realized. Never assume.

Comment: Kotlin is doing good work rehabilitating the humble null!